# Como crear una lista en c#

Tags: c#, lista

¿Cómo hacer una lista genérica propia sin usar List<>? A lo que he llegado siguiendo algunos ejemplos hechos en clase pero implementados en java:

```
public class ListaGenerica<E>
{

    private int size = 0;
    private E[] data;

    public ListaGenerica()
    {

    }
    public ListaGenerica(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;

    }
    public void sizeE()
    {
        data = (new object[size]);
    }
    public Boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return size == 0;
    }
    public E get(int i)
    {
        return data[i];
    }
    public void set(int i, E e)
    {
        data[i] = e;
    }
    public void add(int i, E e)
    {
        if (size == data.Length) // not enough capacity
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Array is full");
        }
        for (int k = size - 1; k >= i; k--) // start by shifting rightmost
         data[k + 1] = data[k];

        data[i] = e; // ready to place the new element size++;
    }
    public E remove(int i)
    {
        E temp = data[i];
        for (int k = i; k < size - 1; k++)
            data[k] = data[k + 1];
        data[size - 1] = default(E);
        size--;
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Luis, te ocurre algun error? Que exactamente es lo que estas preguntando? No esta claro lo que preguntas.

Comment: Quiero crear una clase que haga lo mismo que List<> en Visual Estudio 2015 implementando la estructura basica de una lista,

Comment: Y ocurre algun error con tu implementacion?

Comment: Principalmente en                                                                                      public void set(int i, E e)
    {
        data[i] = e;
    }                                                                                                                         me tira NullReferenceException

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y especifica donde te lanza el error y el mensaje que te muestra para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ademas no encuentro la manera que cuando ingreso el tamano de la lista no se aplica a mi arreglo de E[]

Comment: Y porque simplemente heredas de `ArrayList<T>`?

Comment: Ese fue el ejemplo que me dieron pero yo solo quiero una lista generica con add remove, etc.

Comment: Luis, para poder ayudarte tienes que tener un problema en concreto y no lo estas dando. Organiza las ideas y especifica cual es el problema y el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No queda claro es porqué quieres implementar algo como `List<T>` si ya existe esa clase. En cuanto al error que tienes, nunca estas inicializando `data`, debes hacerlo en los constructores:

```
public ListaGenerica(int size)
{
    data= data = new E[size];
}
```

Pero tienes otro problema. Como estas utilizando un array, en el constructor sin parámetros no podrías inicializar el objeto, ya que en C# un array debe ser instanciado con un tamaño fijo.Asi que deberías hacerlo con un tamaño de 0:

```
public ListaGenerica()
{
    data= data = new E[0];
}
```

Esto choca con tu implementación de `add`, que en ese caso debería redimensionar el array para dejar espacio al nuevo elemento, haciendo algo asi:

```
E[] newData = new E[tamaño];
Array.Copy(data, 0, newdata, 0, tamaño);
data = newData;
```

Estas son solo unas pinceladas, pero en estos casos siempre es mejor ver como lo hacen los buenos. Aqui te dejo la implementación de `List` de Microsoft, estudiandolo puedes aprender cual es la mejor manera de implementar tu código: [List Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9808f1f5ef16c436)